# chrome developer tools not showing traffic

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, telegram

I was trying to understand how https://webk.telegram.org works, so I opened chrome dev tools and went to inspect the network traffic.

I was surprised to see that when I send a message in telegram I don't see any xhr nor websocket traffic in chrome dev tools.

Any idea through which channel the traffic is going ? Why is it not intercepted by chrome network inspector (and can this be fixed)?

Comment: It's a bug in devtools. Use Fiddler or Charles or a similar interception tool.